# Set SwiftUI PageTabViewStyle vertical flow direction in TabView

Tags: swift, swiftui, wwdc

It is now possible to create a horizontal scrolling page controller with the modifier:

```
.tabViewStyle(PageTabViewStyle())
```

By default, pages are presented horizontally. How can it be modified to scroll vertically the same way that `UIPageViewController` can?

Comment: Before asking "how" you'd check "if" it is present at all. I don't see anything like it in Xcode 12 SwiftUI.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I found an efficient way to obtain this, inspired by Ernist answer.

```swift
GeometryReader { proxy in
    TabView(selection: selection) {
        everyView
            .frame(width: proxy.size.width, height: proxy.size.height)
            .rotationEffect(.degrees(-90))
            .rotation3DEffect(flippingAngle, axis: (x: 1, y: 0, z: 0))
    }
    .frame(width: proxy.size.height, height: proxy.size.width)
    .rotation3DEffect(flippingAngle, axis: (x: 1, y: 0, z: 0))
    .rotationEffect(.degrees(90), anchor: .topLeading)
    .offset(x: proxy.size.width)
}.tabViewStyle(PageTabViewStyle())
```

I have also built a [swift package (VerticalTabView )](https://github.com/lorenzofiamingo/SwiftUI-VerticalTabView) that gives the possibility to wrap all that code in this:

```swift
VTabView {
    everyView
}.tabViewStyle(PageTabViewStyle())
```

Comment: Oh man... I made this so complicated before I came here and found this. ‍♂️ Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you need

```
.tabViewStyle(PageTabViewStyle())
.rotationEffect(.degrees(90))
```

Comment: This flips my view 90 degrees, not what @Lorenzo Fiamingo is asking, Could be expanded by also flipping the views.