# How to implement vertical scroll page on watchOS with SwiftUI

Tags: swiftui, watchos

I want to implement a vertical scroll page like system workout app.
[image]

Now I can get a similar effect with this:

```swift
    TabView {
      page1
        .rotationEffect(.degrees(90))
      page2
        .rotationEffect(.degrees(90))
    }.tabViewStyle(.page(indexDisplayMode: .automatic))
    .rotationEffect(.degrees(-90))
```

But not  good as system workout app does. It supports digital crown and dynamic show indicator and custom color.

[image: mysolution]

So , how to implement that vertical scroll effect?

Comment: This might help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62533685/set-swiftui-pagetabviewstyle-vertical-flow-direction-in-tabview

Comment: That is a custom `View` attached to the crown. You likely need the `TabView` with `selection` that is also set by this custom `View`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In watchOS, you can apply `.tabViewStyle(.carousel)` on the `TabView` to make it exactly like you want:

```
TabView{
  Text("Page 1")
  Text("Page 2")
  Text("Page 3")
}
.tabViewStyle(.carousel) //  Here
```

> It seems you should use `.verticalPage` from iOS 17

<sub>Note that this is only for the watchOS</sub>

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/fredyshox/PageView

This repo works well except crown supports.